# how to animate canvas using this plug in

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im still new to this type of programming, im trying to create kaledoscope kind of effect to be projected on screen. I want to make the image move isnide each section of the effect. is there a way to move it? i cant seem to target the canvas created by the plug in.

https://codepen.io/muspelheim/pen/gpymF

```
     var images = [
  "http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/5d/d8/41/5dd8416cbae27edeac61aa525a5df99d.jpg",
  "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FpxaoVBBxXs/T5aWaP2dMDI/AAAAAAAAAw8/qdaPYyuqSt8/s1600/spugnaepicinfame.jpg",
  "https://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9ls7nRTuR1rvqbato1_1280.jpg",
  "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-SJAKrZTcqwI/T5kwYk71YCI/AAAAAAAAAxE/HNlX3i2-xwk/s1600/spugnabimbofango.jpg"
];


// Let's create graphemescope object inside the container
var container = $("#container");
var scope = new Graphemescope( container[0] );


var index = 0;
function changePicture() {
    scope.setImage(images[index]);  
    index = (index + 1) % images.length;
};

setInterval(changePicture, 2000);
changePicture();

$(window).mousemove(function(event) {
  var factorx = event.pageX / $(window).width();
  var factory = event.pageY / $(window).height()

  // This will move kaleidoscope
  scope.angleTarget = factorx;
  scope.zoomTarget  = 1.0 + 0.5 * factory;
});


var resizeHandler = function() {
  container.height( $(window).height() );
  container.width( $(window).width() );
};

$(window).resize(resizeHandler);
$(window).resize();

container.click(changePicture);
```

Comment: are you trying to recreate the codepen linked?

Comment: yes, but with animation!